# Trim spaces from a field when selecting

Tags: php, mysql, select, trim

I'm trying to remove spaces from a field (before and after the name)

```
SELECT TRIM(name) AS new_name FROM users;
```

But it doesn't do anything, and as I have looked at MySQL dev pages, the query looks right.
Am I missing anything?

Have also tried both LTRIM & RTRIM but same result.

Comment: Are you sure there are spaces there?

Comment: Can you supply some example data?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ekgxhSkS

Comment: it works for me. e.g. select trim('          a-user-name');

Comment: `select trim(' a-user-name');` don't you need to specify the table name in your query?

Comment: some spaces are actually "&nbsp;"..

Comment: @vlzvl, also tried that, but same result. Can the TRIM function be disabled on a server? because I'm using a shared hosting.

Comment: have u tried REPLACE() ? (to verify start/end white spaces, regardless the in-between - not as a solution)

Comment: Well it didn't do anything. I'm getting to wonder if it's actually a space or something else, is there anyway to dump the raw data from the field and view it's source to see what those blank parts represent?

Comment: @JohanLarsson . . . you can use the `ASCII()` function to determine the actual character value of any character in a string.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT HEX(TRIM(name)) FROM users;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I placed a dot before and after each row, than used

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX
```

to extract the name only from the result, that way I got what I needed.
Thanks everybody for your answers.